# 2005 Honda Civic no acceleration and bad shifting

Tags: honda, civic, shifting, acceleration

So I got home friday night and ran out of gas pulling into my driveway, ( I wasnt really paying attention to my gas gauge ). I had plans over the weekend with family so we took my girlfriends car wherever we had to go all weekend. I got home Sunday and put gas in my car from a gas can and then went to start it and my battery was dead as well from leaving my key in the ignition one click up to on. I jump started my car that same night and it ran fine so I figured there were no problems. Monday morning comes around and I leave for work and my car dies a mile from the house so I put more gas in it and jump it again. This time when I take off, it has a severe loss of acceleration and it is revving real high with jerky shifts and will not shift over 3rd gear. I take it to local auto parts store and they test my alternator and say that could be my problem with loss of power and acceleration so I take it home and put in a new alternator and we still have the same problem. Severe loss of acceleration and high revs/bad shifts. HELP ME OUT. Thank you!

Comment: you likely sucked up a whole load of dirt from the tank being so low and have blocked some part of the fuel system...